# Delay Javascript Window.open function by 2 seconds

Tags: javascript

i need to delay poping up this window by 2 seconds, when a user hovers over the link.

```
function open_window() 
{
new_window = open("http://www.mysite.com","site","width=610,height=510,left=600,top=400");
}


<a href="#" onMouseOver="javascript:open_window();" >Popup</a>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<a href="#" onMouseOver="setTimeout(open_window,2000);" >Popup</a>
```